# Pharo Smalltalk UITheme builder label

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I am building a GUI app using Smalltalk Pharo version 4.0. I am using the following UITheme builder code to create labels since Morphic TextMorphs/LabelMorphs do not implement Observer pattern to update them dynamically on GUI when their value changes through program logic:

```
UITheme builder
    newLabelFor: self
    getLabel: #labelValue
    getEnabled: nil
```

I need to change the fonts and text color for the above label. I tried using the following and other similar options but it does not work for me:

```
newLabelGroup: labelsAndControls font: aFont labelColor: aColor
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can send the messages `#color:` and `#font:` to the object returned by  `#newLabelFor:getLabel:getEnabled`. For example the code below creates a big red text:

```
(UITheme builder
    newLabelFor: 'Text'
    getLabel: #asString
    getEnabled: nil)
       color: Color red;
       font: (LogicalFont familyName: 'Source Sans Pro' pointSize: 30);
       openInWorld
```

Depending on your image and setup this will not work with all fonts.